# Background color css does not apply properly

Tags: html, css

```
 <div id="popup-data"><h3 class="display-title">Selected Items</h3>

        <div class="taxonomy-fancybox-item-wrapper">
<div class="parent-li"><h3>
<a href="/ajax/remove-term/1" class="delete-parent-link">X</a> Test 1A:
</h3>
</div>
<div class="child-li">Test 2A <a href="/ajax/remove-term/2/1" class="delete-child-link">X</a>
</div>
<div class="child-li">Test 3A <a href="/ajax/remove-term/3/1" class="delete-child-link">X</a>
</div>
</div>
<div class="taxonomy-fancybox-item-wrapper">
<div class="parent-li"><h3><a href="/ajax/remove-term/5" class="delete-parent-link">X</a> Test 1B:</h3></div><div class="child-li">Test 2B <a href="/ajax/remove-term/6/5" class="delete-child-link">X</a></div></div><div class="taxonomy-fancybox-item-wrapper"><div class="parent-li"><h3><a href="/ajax/remove-term/9" class="delete-parent-link">X</a> Test 1C:</h3></div><div class="child-li">Test 2C <a href="/ajax/remove-term/10/9" class="delete-child-link">X</a></div><div class="child-li">Test 3C <a href="/ajax/remove-term/11/9" class="delete-child-link">X</a></div></div><div class="taxonomy-fancybox-item-wrapper"><div class="parent-li"><h3><a href="/ajax/remove-term/13" class="delete-parent-link">X</a> Test 1D:</h3></div><div class="child-li">Test 2D <a href="/ajax/remove-term/14/13" class="delete-child-link">X</a></div><div class="child-li">Test 3D <a href="/ajax/remove-term/15/13" class="delete-child-link">X</a></div><div class="child-li">Test 4D <a href="/ajax/remove-term/16/13" class="delete-child-link">X</a></div><div class="child-li">Test 5D <a href="/ajax/remove-term/17/13" class="delete-child-link">X</a></div></div>  
    </div>
```

Style added for popup-data is(in a css file)

```
#popup-data {
  background-color:aliceblue;
}
```

What is see is background-color is incorrectly added as shown below
[image]
What is incorrect in the html, I even checked but did not find any incomplete div

Comment: Please include the relevant CSS to provide an [example that demonstrates the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Bet it's an overflow issue because of other code which we can't see from your example.  If you don't include a working example we'll never know, but if you wanted to try adding `overflow: auto` to your `#popup-data` properties there's a pretty good chance that'll sort it.  Also, I'd add a class to `#popup-data` as well, and then target that through the CSS rather than the ID as it's marginally more efficient.